# Simpler way to pass scope variables into a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a controller with many $scope.variables

```
$scope.users = userService.getUsers();
$scope.selectedAvailableGroups;
$scope.selectedAssignedGroups;
$scope.availableGroups;
$scope.assignedGroups;
```

I have functions in my controller which uses a service and the service needs arguements passed to it:

```
$scope.removeUserFromGroup = function (){
  userService.removeUserFromGroup($scope.selectedUser,$scope.selectedAssignedGroups, $scope.availableGroups, $scope.assignedGroups)
};
```

Has you can see, the `removeUserFromGroup` function is taking in 4 arguments, but the name is long and it doesn't really seem efficient.

Is this really the best way to do this or am I doing something wrong?

I have a function called addUserToGroup and it's using basically the exact same arguements, seems redundant that I'd need to pass that information to the service again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're concerned about readability, you could format the call like this (which I think reads a bit better):

```
$scope.removeUserFromGroup = function (){
    userService.removeUserFromGroup(
        $scope.selectedUser,
        $scope.selectedAssignedGroups, 
        $scope.availableGroups, 
        $scope.assignedGroups
    );
};
```

If you're really bothered about the number of parameters, and they're likely to increase, you could pass them as properties of a single object:

```
$scope.removeUserFromGroup = function (){
    userService.removeUserFromGroup({
        selectedUser: $scope.selectedUser,
        selectedGroups: $scope.selectedAssignedGroups, 
        availableGroups: $scope.availableGroups, 
        assignedGroups: $scope.assignedGroups
    });
};
```

Comment: That would - http://jsfiddle.net/LfEtp/1/. It seems a bit odd creating a model property on the scope because, in essence, the scope object is a view model itself. Also in your more recent example, you're passing in the list of users to the service which you just retrieved it from. Since the service already has this information, why pass it back and forwards?

Comment: Given your comment about the $scope already being the model, could I just not pass in the $scope itself into the function?  userService.removeUserFromGroup($scope) instead of having to create another object called model? And yea right. I wouldn't need the user object since it's already in the service, good call.

Comment: You could definitely do that, but I think it's probably considered bad practice as you'd be coupling the service to the particular controller that sets up that scope. Also, potentially, you could be passing a whole bunch of additional information that is unnecessary and possibly confusing to someone else trying to understand your code. Imagine that you wanted to call that service from other controllers - you don't want to end up having to mimic the exact scope structure required by each of your services in each of the controllers which uses them. That would get unmanageable pretty quickly.

Comment: Unless I'm really misunderstanding what you're trying to do, I can't think of anything better than the two options I've suggested. Personally I'd go for the first, as I think it's easier to understand.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to reduce having to pass in so many variables into service functions. But if it's not good practice to pass in the $scope, I'll just format my function to make it more readable like you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Although it really depends on the application, perhaps the variables in your scope have more to do with business logic and should be stored in the service. If they are needed by the view, the controller can access and scope the variables from the service, but does not need to send all of them back to the service except when they change.

Comment: I never thought about putting the variables in the service. It seems to me that having the user array come from the user service right. I'll give this a shot.